# Javascript, how to select using DOM xpath something between <br> tag

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

How to select something between `<br>` tag, using xpath or maybe suggest other solution.
so far this is my code where I select the `<p>` but I need what is between `<br>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>some text <br>select this </br>and not this</p>
<div id="insert"></div>
<script>
data = document;
var headings = data.evaluate("//p", data, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
var selectedText = "Selected: <br>";
while (thisHeading) {
    selectedText += thisHeading.textContent + "<br>";
    thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();
}
document.getElementById('insert').innerHTML = selectedText;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `</br>` is not valid HTML as the `br` element is an empty element.

As far as XPath is concerned, you could use the path `//p/br[1]/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]` to select the text node with the string value `select this` and to select an empty node set in case the following sibling of the first `br` child is not a text node.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `<br>` is the only tag that will be in `p`. Youl could split on each `<br>` tags to get an array of elements.

*NOTE: `</br>` is invalid.*

```
var strings = 'some text <br>select this <br/>and not this'.split(/<br\/?>/i);
alert(strings.length); //3
```